# Переименовать ключи в хэше ruby

Tags: ruby

Имеется хэш:

```
{ "BR"=>2, "RU"=>3 }
```

Хочу получить:

```
{ "Brazil"=>2, "Russia"=>3 }
```

Вопрос: Как переименовать ключи хэша, сохранив значения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Если  у вас есть в распоряжении ActiveSupport (или Rails, его содержащий)**, то у вас есть в арсенале [метод `transform_keys`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) (и [деструктивный `transform_keys!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys-21)), дело только за блоком, что сопоставит старым ключам новые.

#### Как это работает?

`transform_keys` собирает новый хэшмап, применив переданный блок к ключам в исходном, используя возвращённые им значения в качестве ключей. Или, проще говоря, переименовывает ключи в хэшмапе блоком. То есть, прямо решает задачу.

#### Теперь о блоке преобразования ключей.

В теории в блоке можно что угодно написать. Вызвать любой справочник, дёрнуть базу.

```
old_keyed_hash.transform_keys do |старый_ключ|
  # выражение, возвращающее новый ключ
  #   Something.lookup_by_country_key(старый_ключ)
  #   SomeModel.find_by(key: старый_ключ).value
  #   старый_ключ[0..1].upcase # плохая идея
end
```

Приведу пару подходов для простейшего случая, хэшмапа. Их можно натянуть и на другие способы сопоставления.

Если взять у хэшмапа метод `[]`*, получится проц (функция, грубо говоря), которая принимает ключ, а возвращает значение.

Любой проц можно передать в вызов метода в качестве блока с префиксом `&`.

В Ruby 2.4 пошли дальше и сделали метод `Hash#to_proc`, работающий аналогично, только метод `to_proc` вызывается неявно, если объект передают в качестве блока.

Результат выглядит следующим образом (можно построчно выполнить в `irb` или `pry`):

```
# Подготовительная часть
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash' # точечный require, тянущий только нужную часть AS

old_keyed_hash = { "BR"=>2, "RU"=>3 }                # исходные данные
key_mapping = { "BR" => "Brazil", "RU" => "Russia" } # этот самый хэшмап с ключами

# Собственно, решение
old_keyed_hash.transform_keys(&key_mapping.method(:[]))
# Или, для Ruby 2.4+
old_keyed_hash.transform_keys(&key_mapping)
```

---

* если название метода вас озадачило, то вот эквивалентные примеры:
  `a[b]` <=> `a.[](b)` <=> `a.public_send(:[], b)`

Comment: вместо хэша key_mapping мне нужно использовать gem countries, пока что ни с одним из перечисленных ответов его завязать не получилось

Comment: @MaksimChanturia что помешало?

Comment: пока что я не понимаю, но то что нужно было, я узнал

Answer (score 1):

```
mappings = { "BR" => "Brazil", "RU" => "Russia" }

{ "BR"=>2, "RU"=>3 }.map { |key, value| [mappings[key] || key, value] }.to_h
```

Внутри map вы проходите по каждой паре `ключ => значение`, и трансформируете эту пару в массив `[ключ, значение]`. Полученный массив массивов потом трансформируете в хеш через `.to_h`.

При этом внутри map старый ключ вы трансформируете в новый вот так:

```
mappings[key] || key
```

Здесь вы обращаетесь к хешу `mappings` со старым ключом, из которого вы либо получаете новый ключ, либо `nil`, если по старому ключу там ничего нет. В случае с `nil` сработает инструкция `nil || key`, и в новом ключе будет просто ваш старый неизмененный `key`.

Comment: можете пояснить немного, что здесь происходит `{ |key, value| [mappings[key] || key, value] }`

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Как пишут в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19298437/3116253) :

hash[:<Новый ключ>] = hash.delete :<Старый ключ>